# Controller without Authentication when using VS2013 Organizational Auth web template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

How can I configure a controller to have no authentication at all when using the Organizational Accounts template from Visual Studio 2013? I thought the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) is used in MVC to mark a controller or action as protected. But in this template it seems that implicitly all Controllers are by default protected. In my situation a need an unprotected controller as some sort of welcome/landing page, without automatically redirecting to login page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Add `[AllowAnonymous]` on your controller.